# How to see lots of spots on a graph clearly?

Tags: python, plot, scatter

I have 1,000,000 points on a graph and I want to see them separately. 
 X-axis is between (0.1 to 1000) and Y-axis is between (0-1.2) But it seems like I have a block and I cant read it at all. 
I have already tried to decrease the marker size but it stil doesn't help me to read the plot. Is there anyway I can see them clearly or separately?

here is my code that provides me the data:

```py
d50 = 0.15*10**(-3)  
D = 0.4 
mean = 0 
sd = 1     
fi = 20  

n = np.random.normal(mean, sd, 10000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(n, 30, density=True)

for i in range(0, 105): # Calculations to make point's Y axis and X axis
    x = []
    y = []
    Re = 0.1 * (1.1**i)  
    B = e ** (-0.08 * Re) * (2.5 * np.log(Re) + 5.25) + 8.5 * (1 - e ** (-0.08 * Re))  
    C = 0.8+0.9*((e**(-0.08*Re)/(Re**2))+((1-e**(-0.08*Re))/(B**2)))**(-0.5)  # C=ub/u star
    F = 0.31*Re*e**(-0.1*Re)+1.8*e**(-0.88*d50/D)*(1-e**(-0.1*Re))  
    A = F/C   

    for j in range(10000):
        Dcbss = 0.52*math.tan(fi) / (((1 + (abs(n[j])*A))**2)*(1+(1/2.5)*((abs(n[j])*F)**2)*math.tan(fi)))
        x.append(Re)
        y.append(Dcbss)

    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', marker='o', markersize=0.7)


plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the thing I was doing here was wrong. There is no way I could have read the plot clearly. Because it was 1 million points and so dense so it showed me a block plot. There is no proper answer for this question and I wanted to answer this so it won't be a conflict to anyone.

Comment: Maybe you can plot a sub-sample of it?